# Use only custom label in X-axis in .NET chart

Tags: c#, .net, charts, linechart, axis-labels

I'm making a .NET line graph in C# with an X-axis interval of weeks. For my project, I only want to be using the custom label, but for now I still want the gridlines. Does anyone know a way to hide the default X-Axis labels while still keeping the custom labels?

I tried this:

```
Chart4.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
```

The obvious result is that there were no labels applied, which is not what I was trying to do.

**EDIT:** 
The code for generating the original rows was this:

```
Chart4.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "M";
```

And the code for the custom label was this:

```
int month = XValues[0].Month;
var XAxis = Chart4.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;

DateTime StartMonthPos = XValues[0];
DateTime EndPos = new DateTime();

foreach (DateTime Date in XValues)
{
    EndPos = Date;

    if (Date.Month != month)
    {
        Chart4.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(StartMonthPos.ToOADate(), EndPos.ToOADate(), StartMonthPos.ToString("MMMM"), 1, LabelMarkStyle.None);
        StartMonthPos = Date;
    }

    month = Date.Month;
}

XAxis.CustomLabels.Add(StartMonthPos.ToOADate(), EndPos.ToOADate(), StartMonthPos.ToString("MMMM"), 1, LabelMarkStyle.None);
```

The chart looks like this: [image: Chart with dates]

And it should look like this: [image: chart without dates]

Comment: You might want to look into column charts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright, I looked into `Label` controls on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456628%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). In order to make the custom label appear in place of the normal label, I set the `RowIndex` parameter to `0`, replacing the default label row. The final code for the custom rows looked like this:

```
    int month = XValues[0].Month;
    var XAxis = Chart4.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;

    DateTime StartMonthPos = XValues[0];
    DateTime EndPos = new DateTime();

    foreach (DateTime Date in XValues)
    {
        EndPos = Date;

        if (Date.Month != month)
        {
           Chart4.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(StartMonthPos.ToOADate(),
              EndPos.ToOADate(), StartMonthPos.ToString("MMMM"), 0, LabelMarkStyle.None);
            StartMonthPos = Date;
        }

        month = Date.Month;
    }

    XAxis.CustomLabels.Add(StartMonthPos.ToOADate(), EndPos.ToOADate(),
          StartMonthPos.ToString("MMMM"), 0, LabelMarkStyle.None);
```