# Display x-axis label at certain data-points in mschart

Tags: vb.net, winforms, mschart

I'm trying to plot a normal distribution curve (as a SeriesChartType.Spline) with a selected items location on that curve. My x-axis is a little messy so I'm trying to tidy it up but I can't figure a way to show the axis label at specific locations.

I'd like to show the value at {x(0), x(mean), x(n)} and also the x-axis value of the selected item's data-point on the curve.

[image]

I've tried playing with the

```
.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval
```

but I don't necessarily have a standard interval range.

Is there a way I can display the x-axis label only at specified data points?

[EDIT]:

As suggested I implemented several custom labels for this chart. They are not exactly what I'd call intuitive to use but they did the job in the end.

```
'//create x-axis labels
mu = Math.Round(mu, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
bci = Math.Round(CDbl(bci), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
Dim muLabel = String.Format("{0}({1})", "µ", mu)

'//Fit axis
With .ChartAreas(0)
    With .AxisX
        .MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0
        .MajorTickMark.Enabled = false
        .Minimum = 0
        With .CustomLabels
            .Add(New CustomLabel(0, 0.4, 0, 0, LabelMarkStyle.LineSideMark))                        '//origin label
            .Add(New CustomLabel(mu-10, mu + 10, muLabel, 0, LabelMarkStyle.LineSideMark))          '//mean label)
            .Add(New CustomLabel(bci-10, bci + 10, bci.ToString, 0, LabelMarkStyle.LineSideMark))   '//index label
        End With
        With .LabelStyle
            .Format = "{0.00}"
            .Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8)
        End With
...
```

The ranges I picked for the labels are a bit arbitrary. My data distribution is not going to change much immediately so I picked a range that looked reasonable with the font so the labels sit in the centre. Looks much more readable now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VV4yd.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a choice of either

- Replacing the normal labels by `CustomLabels`. They are a bit tricky since you can't set their position. Instead you need **two** positions (`FromPosition` and `ToPosition`) to declare the range where the `CustomLabel` shall be centered. Note that once you use `CustomLabels` **no normal ones will show**.
- Or you can add `TextAnnotations`. You can set `AnchorX` to the value you want and the `Y` position to the minimum of your y-values. Getting these right is also a little tricky, involving the axes of the `Annotation` and also the `IsSizeAlwaysRelative` which should be false.
- Or you could code the `Pre`- or `PostPaint` events and `Graphics.DrawString` or `TextRenderer.DrawText` the text you want using the `ValueToPixelPosition` axes functions to get the coordinates. This may actually be the easiest to do..

Comment: I finally got around to revisitng this. I went for the Custom labels. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Some overloads of the custom label collection .Add() has a rowIndex parameter. Custom labels CAN coexist with default labels.

Each custom label has a rowindex property. If set >0 multiple label rows are possible.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.customlabelscollection?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: True but this means that each type sits on a separate row. But I'll update the answer to mention this later..

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with [custom labels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.axis.customlabels(v=vs.110).aspx) ([example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17835037/1530)), but might need to do some extra fiddling to hide the normal labels ([example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13996488/1530)).